Need advice on approaches to saving data
The following code(JSFiddle here) is a grid-based code where I'm performing the following steps:
I’m moving blue boxes from left to right (on the grid) after clicking Move Text Content! button. Here are the steps I follow:

Select one option from the Select Options dropdown.
Select a color from the dropdown.
Click the Show Options button
Enter a row and column (For example A and 1) and then click calculate
Hit the Move Text Content! button to move blue boxes on the grid.

My plan is to save all the grid-related details (I’ll thinking of having a save button somewhere on top of the grid which will achieve this) in a database table and I have yet to design the table. I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on the same like what columns I should consider and what should I consider saving.
Here are some of my thoughts:

Since I’ll be saving the contents inside the grid, I will have to have a column for storing the values of the divs (blue text box content that goes on the grid) like Option#1, Option#2 etc.

2.Since I am also having different colors on the grid. I believe I should be storing the CSS for those specific divs as well. Not sure if saving CSS info sounds reasonable in terms of database design.

I might want to save the cell value which drives the pattern.

A user can also edit the text once it's on the grid so that's also one possibility.
Is there anything anyone could think of that could be worth considering to save or something I should avoid and handle differently from the above-mentioned points? Thanks!
P.S. Since this is an advise related question, I'm asking here and not on stack overflow.And since I can't include a working code just like I can do it in StackOverflow, hence I've included a JSFiddle link. But let me know if anything needs to change.
